# How to decrease memory usage in binary tree

Tags: java, performance, memory-management, binary-tree

I have solved the task below, but one point of it is performance of the solution matters! Note that the memory limit for the tests is set to 128 MB (-Xmx128M). After running performance test, I get an OutOfMemoryError.

How can I decrease memory consumption?

Each line in the file can be one of the following:

*Updates* to the limit order book in the following format:

```
u,<price>,<size>,bid - set bid size at <price> to <size>
u,<price>,<size>,ask - set ask size at <price> to <size>
```

*Queries* in the following format:

```
q,best_bid - print best bid price and size
q,best_ask - print best ask price and size
q,size,<price> - print size at specified price (bid, ask or spread).
```

And *market orders* in the following format:

```
o,buy,<size> - removes <size> shares out of asks, most cheap ones.
o,sell,<size> - removes <size> shares out of bids, most expensive ones
```

Queries, market orders, and limit order book updates are in arbitrary sequence. Each line in the file is one of the three and ends with a UNIX newline character.

```
public class LimitBook {

  private final TreeMap<Integer,Integer> bidTree = new TreeMap<>();
  private final TreeMap<Integer,Integer> askTree = new TreeMap<>();

  public void addToBidTree(Integer price, Integer size) {
    if (bidTree.containsKey(price)) {
      bidTree.put(price, size);
    } else {
      bidTree.put(price, size);
    }
  }

  public void addToAskTree(Integer price, Integer size) {
    if (askTree.containsKey(price)) {
      askTree.put(price,size);
    } else {
      askTree.put(price,size);
    }
  }

  public Integer findByPrice(Integer price) {
    if (bidTree.containsKey(price)) {
      return bidTree.get(price);
    } else if (askTree.containsKey(price)) {
      return askTree.get(price);
    }
    return 0;
  }

  private Integer findBestAsk() {
    Integer key = askTree.firstKey();
    while (askTree.get(key) == 0) {
      key = askTree.higherKey(key);
    }
    return key;
  }

  private Integer findBestBid() {
    Integer key = bidTree.lastKey();
    while (bidTree.get(key) == 0) {
      key = bidTree.lowerKey(key);
    }
    return key;
  }

  public String printBestBid() {
    int bestBidKey = findBestBid();
    return bestBidKey + "," + bidTree.get(bestBidKey);
  }

  public String printBestAsk() {
    int bestAskKey = findBestAsk();
    return bestAskKey + "," + askTree.get(bestAskKey);
  }

  public void marketBuy(Integer size) {
    int restSize = size;
    while(restSize > 0) {
      Integer bestAskKey = findBestAsk();
      Integer limitSize = askTree.get(bestAskKey);
      if (limitSize > restSize) {
        askTree.put(bestAskKey,limitSize-restSize);
        restSize -= limitSize;
      } else {
        restSize -= limitSize;
        askTree.put(bestAskKey,0);
      }
    }
  }

  public void marketSell(Integer size) {
    int restSize = size;
    while(restSize > 0) {
      Integer bestBidKey = findBestBid();
      Integer limitSize = bidTree.get(bestBidKey);
      if (limitSize > restSize) {
        bidTree.put(bestBidKey,limitSize-restSize);
        restSize -= limitSize;
      } else {
        restSize -= limitSize;
        bidTree.put(bestBidKey,0);
      }
    }
  }
```

UPD. This is error message :
Your solution produced the correct output but failed the performance test.
Please, note that using too much memory can sometimes result in a timeout due to GC overhead - in other words, this timeout might actually be an OutOfMemoryError. This error might also occur due to wrong data produced during the performance test.

UPD1: This is the full message :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3822)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.newString(StringLatin1.java:766)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2708)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.split(String.java:3137)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.split(String.java:3195)
    at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

.So the problem in the main class when i create new String. How to solve it?

Comment: `*i get exception after submitting it, i think this is because of memory*` -- what exception do you get?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I can't see the full message, because .jar is running not on my machine. This is only i received (Failed - exception thrown).

Comment: Ok.  So are you saying that the program *does not* throw any exception when you do run it on your own machine?

Comment: No. Probably because i run it with little data, but i don't know how many data they put it in their tests. So this my only thoughts about possible exception, cause the task have limit of 128mb. I think the problem can be while reading the file with BufferedReader so i change it on Scanner, but i still getting exception.

Comment: It's unclear what the nature of the problem is, and I don't see any smoking gun in the code posted, but consider (1) avoiding recursion; (2) avoiding scanning whole lines and creating `String` versions of numbers - you know what kinds of tokens to expect from reading the first few characters of each input line; (3) using `TreeMap` instead of a custom tree implementation; (4) eliminating the `Order` class - you need only map prices (keys) to sizes (values), so `Order` seems to be overkill.

Comment: There might be other optimizations available based on input limits (which you have not disclosed), such as on the maximum price asked or bid, or on the maximum number of input lines.

Comment: Just to confirm, though: the problem does specify input from a file named "input.txt", and output to a file named "output.txt", as demonstrated by your code, right?  Because it's very common for programs evaluated by automated judges to instead be expected to take input from their standard input stream and to be expected to write output to their standard output stream.  If that's the expectation of *your* program then the exception you receive likely is related to attempting to access files, not to memory usage.

Comment: @JohnBollinger i know the limits for max  price and bid (1 bln). In my task it's clearly sad that i nedd to read from file with name "input.txt" and do output to "output.txt.I received exception only after running 5 Test so i think this is not the problem. I want to clarify one thing about your suggestion about elimination Order class, you want me to use HashMap with only one key and value or what?

Comment: I am not suggesting use of `HashMap` to represent individual orders.  Supposing that you have a `Map` from prices to bids and another from prices to asks, the only thing each one needs to record about an individual bid or ask is the amount available -- one `Integer`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I change my solution and my solution is correct, but i have now OutOfMemoryError) Now it's clearly for me that i have problem with memory. Pls suggest me how to decrease memory using.

Comment: The `bidTree` and `askTree` should both be kept minimal: the real life business logic determines that. It helps when you can print the trees to check operations. I do see only adding, not cleaning up on adding. But I did not read much. And then OutOfMemoryExceptions also happen in endless loops and endless recursion, a function (indirectly) calling oneself.

Comment: At first glance, there's not much you can do to reduce the memory footprint. Clearly, most of the memory will be used in the two `TreeMap`s.

Comment: @JoopEggen What do you mean by "not cleaning on adding"?

Comment: I am not familiar with ask/bid trees, but do not existing entries get corrected in price, possibly even deleted; asks and bids influence each other? You just overwrite or add. TL;DR